# File download links returning 404 after .htaccess rewrite

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, http-status-code-404

I rewrote my .htaccess to define a couple of redirects:

- non-www to www
- feed to blogs/feed
- admin to blogs/wp-admin

All these redirects are working perfect. However, this seems to have broken my file download links. For example, I have a download links pointing to:

Mysitedomain/decks/50_Essential_Spanish_Verbs.apkg

I know for a fact that **the file IS there**. Yet every time I click the link, it throws a 404 instead of letting you download the file. Is my htaccess rewrite to blame for this issue? Any suggestions on how to fix it?

Here's what my .htaccess currently looks like:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on

Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([a-z.]+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%1/$1 [R=301,L]
#RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ http://www.thesite.com/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
#Rewrite rule for blog feed
RewriteRule feed blogs/feed/burrorss [NC,L]
#Rewrite rule for blog admin
RewriteRule admin blogs/wp-admin [NC,L]

RewriteRule ^(.*) /index.html [NC,L]

</IfModule>
```

Comment: Does the file really exist on your server?

Comment: I have already answered that question in my question. I will mark it in bold so there's no confusion.

Comment: is the file permission on the physical file correctly set? try changing all file permission to 777 and see if problem still persist.

Comment: The problem could also mean that you have a broken link that didnt not point to the correct directory.

Comment: That would be strange since the link was working just fine until the rewrites and I never tinkered with permissions. But since you mentioned that, how do I even go about changing those permissions given I am on a public shared hosting? Is it possible?

Comment: Broken link? I have already made it clear in the question that the file DOES EXIST at the directory being linked to.